# How to schedule pod between two node pool in GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have having 2 pool in my GKE cluster default-pool (2 nodes), temp-pool (3 nodes). I am having pod replicas as 4 now my requirment is atleast ****minimum one
pod it has to schedule on default-pool its mandatory** (not all the pod should schedule on default pool)** and other pods can schedule on temp pool

I tried using nodeaffinity, topologySpreadConstraints specification but sometimes pod is not scheduling on default-pool

Is there a way to achieve this in kubernetes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node affinity allows you to constrain which nodes your pod is eligible to be scheduled on, based on labels on the node.

As you need that they won't end up on the same node, you can use [AntiAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) along with the weighted  node pool preferences using `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`.

or try this spec on [topologySpreadConstraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/)

```
spec:
  topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: zone
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        node: temp-pool
```